# Facebook Place search with Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to search Facebook using the Graph API without having the user log in? I specifically want to search for Places, but I notice with the example on Facebook's Developers site they include an access token in the URL, which I believe is generated by having the user log in.

Here's a relevant link describing the API: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more searching, I found the "App Login" section of the Authentication page of the Facebook Developers site.

More info here (scroll down to the App login section): [Facebook Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

Using App Login, you can retrieve an access token using your application ID and your app secret, and then use that access token to perform Place searches. This avoids requiring any user interaction.